# Oracle equivalent of a SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, sql-server-2012

I need to know the Oracle equivalent of my SQL Sever query. Could someone please help me?

```
select recno = (select top 1 ld.recno from load ld where ld.crecno = i.recno) 
from inputtable i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Below Query

```
select (select  ld.recno from load ld where ld.crecno = i.recno AND RowNum =1)
AS recno  from inputtable i
```

Comment: can you show me the error description after executing above query ?

Answer (score 1):

### Converting TOP(N) T-SQL Syntax to Oracle Compatible SQL

The `SUBQUERY` you wrote is not necessary.  A `INNER JOIN` operation between the `LOAD` and `INPUTTABLE` tables is a quick way to get the set you are looking for.

> *SQL Syntax Interpretation:*  Of all the records in `LOAD`, how many of the ones with values `CRECNO` have matching values in the column `RECNO` of table `INPUTTABLE`?  Taking those results, what is the FIRST value (TOP(1)) in the output if the results are sorted by...(?)...

There isn't any `SORT` priority designated in the OP.

> In a SELECT statement, always use an ORDER BY clause with the TOP clause. This is the only way to predictably indicate which rows are affected by TOP. [Reference From: Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx).

To illustrate a correctly formatted SQL statement with repeatable results, I went ahead and rewrote the OP's SQL query assuming that the `TOP(n)` solution wanted the first value in an ASCENDING SORT of the `RECNO` column values.

Database servers do have a default sorting and selection behavior if important expressions such as an `ORDER BY` statement are missing, it is risky however to assume that all defaults are set the same in any given environment.

**The Rewritten SQL:**

```
WITH sub_query AS (
     SELECT i.recno
       FROM inputtable i, load ld
      WHERE i.recno = ld.crecno
      ORDER BY i.recno ASC
     )
     SELECT s.recno
       FROM sub_query s
      WHERE rownum = 1
```

> The `ROWNUM` evaluation and the `ORDER BY` criteria can be changed to obtain the `TOP(n)` behavior intended.